# How do I get a variable set in another scope from within a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer function I got off this site and have tried to modify it a bit to suit my needs. For the most part it works as I'd like but I'm not able to pass a parameter to the JavaScript function.

I want to use a select to change the id value, then pass that value into the JQuery load function. Can someone please show me how to do this?

It may be worth mentioning that when the the timer refreshes, the select value needs to "stick", it can't reset.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function RecurringTimer(callback, delay) {
  var timerId, start, remaining = delay;

  this.pause = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    remaining -= new Date() - start;
  };

  var resume = function() {
    start = new Date();
    timerId = window.setTimeout(function() {
      remaining = delay;
      resume();
      callback();
    },remaining);
  };

  this.resume = resume;
  this.resume();
}

var timer = new RecurringTimer(function() {
  $('#id').load('load.asp?id=1'); // The "id" should be "newVal" from JQuery below.
}, 5000);


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#appList').live('change',function(){
    var select = $(this);
    var newVal = select.val();

    if(newVal != ''){

      // This is where the var newVal needs to be passed into the JavaScript.

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: whcih javascript function do you want to pass `newVal` to?

Comment: @SidMS, I'd like to pass it from the .live function into the `var timer`

Comment: It's not really a jQuery to Javascript issue. You're facing a scope problem. Personally, I'd probably wrap that `$(document).ready()` around all of the code you have there so it's in scope, and put the `var newVal` at the `$.ready()` level. Which you could then access from the RecurringTimer scope.

Comment: @user1709311: Is there any reason why you can't use `setInterval()` (aside from the `pause()` method)?

Comment: Here's an example of scoping variables which then stay in scope for event handlers and other scopes that occur within the closure: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/5t2Un/1/

Comment: Thanks Jared. I've already tried to wrap the document.ready function around the JavaScript but then the timer buttons stop working. I'm really a superNoob with JS. Can you please show me how this is done so that the timer buttons still work?

Comment: Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/9PuUx/1/

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: @Blender, no, there isn't but I just suck with JQuery and JavaScript. I don't know how to implement that. WHat I need is a way to start and stop the timer by way of input buttons.

Comment: Also, `$.live()` is deprecated and you should start (getting used to) using [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do:

```
if(newVal != ''){
    window.newVal = newVal;
}
```

And use `window.newVal` where needed:

```
$('#id').load('load.asp?id=' + window.newVal);
```

Comment: Phfft. But why? You've got a closure right there with the `$.ready()`.

Comment: Yes! But the timer definition is outside the ready() closure (as of now). Either, we'll need to put a super closure and add a local variable in that. Or we should put the timer definition inside the ready() function. The above is just the easiest way, definitely not the best.

Comment: If you've got a lot of code dancing around, it can get tricky once it starts getting pushed behind private scope. But usually global can be avoided, and I think in this case the functions could be pushed into that scope a la http://jsfiddle.net/Hpgxd/.

Comment: Yes, in this case its actually just a matter of moving those 2 statements (`timer = ..` and the `ready` handler) into a super closure. Assuming the code above is all there is.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why Jarad is balking at this but I'm happy, it's working. :)  Was this not a good solution?

Comment: It is an okay solution, but not the best. But it is always a good practice to not fill the global namespace (i.e. `window.xyz`) up with app specific variables. This is useful especially if we are using a lot of libraries etc.. that might come with their own set of global stuff.. I hope it is clear. Just a thing of good clean coding.

Comment: @user1709311 - It's "non-optimal". Using `global` (or `window` scope in this case) is like fast food, it's easy and leads to heart disease due to hard to find bugs and other problems. It's best avoided, but you have to learn the techniques to do so too.

Comment: Thanks techfoobar. I also can appreciate good coding practices. I just don't know much at all about JS. I really need to pick up a book or two! Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Thanks for the comment. If someone wants to, for the sake of my learning, post the correct way to do this, I'd appreciate it. I'm really looking not only to solve my issue but to learn some things along the way

Comment: @user1709311 - I was working on something. I've got the fiddle done, so I'll have it up in the next few minutes.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Thank you! I'll wait around for it. I hope you don't mind if I ask you some questions about it because I'm fairly sure I won't understand that much about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've speculated to a degree here what you're up to, so there were some changes I made to accommodate just trying to make it work. So if you have any questions about why I did something, just let me know.

Here's my mock elements, trying to match what you had in your code:

```
<div id="selector">
    <select id="appList">
        <option value="1">Application List - App 1</option>
        <option value="2">Application List - App 2</option>
        <option value="3">Application List - App 3</option>
        <option value="4">Application List - App 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="id"></div>
```

​Note, `#id` is not a good identifier for an element; I almost renamed it to `#loader` several times. You might consider making this `id` attribute for this element more descriptive.

I did change the `$.live` to `$.on`; if the element you're working with in reality is like a `select` or something with a genuine `change` event, stick with `$.on` instead of `$.live`. `$.live` is deprecated and it probably won't be too many more versions before it's removed altogether.

I also switched out `$.load` for `$.get` so I could use the `callback`; jsFiddle doesn't really give me the option of working with `$.load` and returning anything. So I used `$.get` and substituted a log statement instead.

Ok, so what you'll see is a wrapping `jQuery();` around all the `RecurringTimer()` function, as well as the `callback`, `timer`, and `$.on`. What this does is create a "closure scope" (think like it's *enclosing* that code it contains), so I'm no longer in `window` or global scope. I can access `window` by calling `window`, but `this` will belong to `jQuery.ready()`, which implies `document`.

Right at the top you'll see this:

```
jQuery(function run($){
    var $id = $('#id'),
        $applist = $('#appList'),
        timerId,
        start,
        remaining = 0,
        newval,
        select;
```

These are all private variables that will stay in scope for the function and callbacks that belong to this scope. So we can share them if I have them at this "top most private" scope. If they are called with `var` inside of the other functions in this scope, they will only belong to that scope. Like `var select = $(this);` is only accessible within that `$.on` handler.

Hence, I want `var newval;` at that top most private scope, so we can easily share it. You have to be careful, of course, since there are times you don't want to shove it all up to that scope (like `var select`).

Probably the rest of it is self-explanatory. You don't need `window.setTimeout`, just `setTimeout`. Most `window`-scoped properties and methods don't require you to prepend `window`. However, you may need to do so to disambiguate a local and global/`window` property, for instance if you had a local `var location = 'http://...';` in scope. You would need `window.location` to get that in that case.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
jQuery(function run($){
    var $id = $('#id'),
        $applist = $('#appList'),
        timerId,
        start,
        remaining = 0,
        newval,
        select;

    $applist.on('change', function(){
        var select = $(this);

        $id.prepend('<p>App List change event fired</p>');

        newval = select.val();

        if (newval != '') {
            var timer = new RecurringTimer(function() {
                $.get('/echo/html/?id=' + newval, callback); 
            }, 5000);
        }

        function callback(msg, status){
            var report = '<p>Callback returned ' + status + 
                         ' for '  + this.url +  '.</p>';

            $id.prepend(report);
        }
    });

    function RecurringTimer(callback, delay) {
        remaining = delay;

        $id.prepend('<p>RecurringTimer initialized.</p>');

        this.pause = function() {
            clearTimeout(timerId);

            remaining -= new Date() - start;
        };

        var resume = function() {
            start = new Date();

            timerId = setTimeout(function() {
                remaining = delay;
                resume();
                callback();
            }, remaining);
        };

        this.resume = resume;

        this.resume();
    }
});
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/zU5b3/

There's also some CSS, but I don't think it's relevant, so I left it out.

Comment: Jared, thank you. I am going to look this over. I'm certain that I will have some questions for you so I will take a few notes then post back here. In the mean time, thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: Hi Jared, I have a few questions regarding your example. Under the JQuery function, you have `var $id` etc. First off, what is does the dollar sign represent in javascript? I've never seen that before. Also, that same variable has others attached to it with commas. I've never seen this either. Is that a shorthand way of setting everything as a variable? I have others as well but thought I'd start with a couple. :)   Thanks for the help!

Comment: Good questions. I (and some others, I've found) use `$var` to denote a variable which keeps a reference to a jQuery selector object, e.g., `$body = $(document.body);` Now everywhere I use that variable, I know it's a jQuery object and not a DOM node reference (where I would just leave the `$` off). On the second, it's a special situation when you use `var` on a variable name, like `var $body = ...`, since that `var` keyword keeps that variable within that scope and inner scopes (unless there's an inner variable with the same name). So it's really important you absorb that, since... `[...]`

Comment: ... you get what's called local or closure scope, which is what I'm taking advantage of in that fiddle; no other scope can barge in and accidentally or otherwise monkey with my variables, or vice versa. This is the "globals are eViL" argument. The flipside is that you have your own variable to set and use at later times. For instance: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/jULBx/ See how I've saved `$form` and `form`? And then last BIG IDEA is that `var o = ...` and `function f() {...}`, in which the `var` and `function` are declared *first* (and not like `handler = function(){}`, which is...

Comment: ... a variable function), those variables and functions get *hoisted* to the top of the scope. What does that mean? Well, it means that even if you have them declared *after* the first time you call them in the flow of the script, it's already available to use. We take advantage of that above with our `RecurringTimer` call. So closures, local scope, and hoisting: Cool stuff worth understanding.

Comment: I was miraculously able to get your code working to the point where it will populate my div with the get data. I need to use buttons that will pause and start the timer function. Is this set up to do that? What would I call to start and stop the timer?

Comment: OK, so using the `var` keyword, whatever name I give as a variable will only be available within the brackets? Is a variable prepended with a dollar sign available throughout the entire file? Like global in scope?

Comment: To your last comment, no, there is **nothing actually special or different about the actual variable**. You ever know someone, like your Dad maybe, who color coded his keys or had a sister who kept everything stored in a color-coordinated way? They're still keys, still clothes. But they're more easily accessible mentally. That's the `$var`. To me, it says immediately *Oh, that's a jQuery result. I can do jQuery methods with it.* It has no magic due to that, though. It's just a variable to Javascript. And the scope is available to functions and other scope that occur in that scope as well.

Comment: On the button toggles, why don't you take a look at it and think about it and let me know, considering the way it's organized, what you think should be done to make it work like that.

Comment: OK Jared, thanks, I'll do that and be back soon. Also, thank you for the last explanation about the keys, it hit home with me. It's like when I prepend a variable in my application code that indicates to me that it's a private property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function RecurringTimer(callback, delay) {
 var timerId, start, remaining = delay;
 var newValue;
  .....
  .....
  .....
```

and then in your jquery

```
if(newVal != ''){

     newValue = newVal;

}
```

Then you can reference it inside your timer

```
    var timer = new RecurringTimer(function() {

        $('#id').load('load.asp?id='+newValue); // The "id" should be "newVal" from JQuery below.
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt hsalama. Here is what I get: `ReferenceError: newVal is not defined`

Comment: Well, technically it should work, I just copied that part from your code, so you may want to double check that your selectors do match the HTML and so forth

Comment: I just tried it again but it's just coming up with the reference error. All of my selectors match.

Comment: Can you tell from your console which line is giving the error?